# spring framework documentation usage

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**As in spring site isn't allowed to ask question i will write here my question to Spring authors.**

I would like to know how supposed to use spring documentation.
I spent a lot of time in Spring boot reference guide. Only for understand how spring boot is working.
There are some examples work principle of which are not explained in documentation. Or explained like this

**11.3.2 The @EnableAutoConfiguration annotation
The second class-level annotation is @EnableAutoConfiguration. This annotation tells Spring Boot to “guess” how you will want to configure Spring, based on the jar dependencies that you have added. Since spring-boot-starter-web added Tomcat and Spring MVC, the auto-configuration will assume that you are developing a web application and setup Spring accordingly.**

And there are nothing about how it works. Some kind of philosophy.

I read a lot of tutorial from other developer and they give the exactly same information as original documentation. Like nobody knows how it really works and what will happen if you will not use tutorial example)).

Now I have to handle another programmers code on spring boot and I can't find answer to one question. What method will call after this application.main?

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.EnvironmentEndpoint;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

import javax.inject.Inject;

/**
 * Root entry of our service, starting the Spring container and configuring our system.

 */
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class Application {


    @Inject
    private EnvironmentEndpoint environmentEndpoint;

    protected Application() {
    }

    /**
     * Main method, used to run the application.
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        application.run(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't usually call another method. The application has set up some sort of services, such as HTTP endpoints or message listeners, that are waiting for interaction.

Comment: Spring Boot is a convenience layer on top of the core Spring framework. You may find it useful to peruse the core Spring [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/), especially the chapter titled "The IoC container".

Comment: You don't need to reference your controllers by name anywhere. If you add the context-drive xml property with the package name which contains your controllers in your spring xml configuration, or use the annotational equivalent, Spring will find your controllers and other resources for you